# How to count points per buffer when the buffers are combined with st_union in R, package: sf

Tags: r, mapping, geospatial, r-sf

Here is the situation:

Brief description: I have buffers that overlap; I want to count the number of stores within a certain number of meters from a school.

I specifically want to know how many stores are within 1000 meters from a school, and how many stores are within 2000 meters from a school, as I want to compare the difference. Of course, some of these school buffers overlap. So while a store may be 1500 m from school A, it is only 750 m from school B. Therefore, it counts as being within 1000 m from a school, and should only be counted as being in the 1000m for school B, and not counted for school A. Where a store is within 2000 m of two schools (but not within 1000 m) it needs to count toward the school it is closest to.

So ideally I want the dataset to look like:

School     |   Stores1000m    |   Stores2000m   |

School A   |        3          |        6         |

School B   |        2          |        7         |

So I used the st_union function in sf to combine the buffers. This worked well for producing a beautiful map, but then when I used lengths and st_intersects to count the stores within the buffers, it only returned a single number for each type of zone (1000 m vs 2000 m)

My code for these portions is below:

```
my.buff <-st_buffer(school.sf.utm, 1000)     
my.buff2 <-st_buffer(school.sf.utm, 2000) 

pts_com<-st_union(my.buff)
pts_pol<-st_cast(pts_com, "POLYGON")

pts_com2<-st_union(my.buff2)
pts_pol2<-st_cast(pts_com2, "POLYGON")

(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(my.buff, store.sf.utm))) #gives per school but ignores overlapping
(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(pts_com, store.sf.utm)))

(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(my.buff2, store.sf.utm)))
(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(pts_com2, store.sf.utm)))
```

What would be the ideal code to do what I need to do? I am very lost on how to make this work. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Thank you for commented @hugh-allan! I have included sample data and a more of the code in a new post in hopes that someone sees it, as I am really stumped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775744/counting-points-when-buffers-are-overlapping-r-package-sf

Comment: Great. I have (hopefully) found you an answer, in the other question you posted. In future, it might be advisable to edit this question and add the sample data in, rather than opening a new (duplicate) question. We might have to close this one so we can focus on the new version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting points when buffers are overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775744/counting-points-when-buffers-are-overlapping)

Comment: Yes. I think so, I will run everything tomorrow. Sorry, stack overflow wasn't allowing me to comment for a bit (because of site work) and then got distracted over the weekend. I will run tomorrow, but reading it over, it seems like it should work with some tweaks. Thank you so much!!!