# Counting points when buffers are overlapping

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, geo

I include all of my code and a link to sample data below.

Brief description: I have buffers that overlap; I want to count the number of stores within a certain number of meters from a school.

I specifically want to know how many stores are within 1000 meters from a school, and how many stores are within 2000 meters from a school, as I want to compare the difference. Of course, some of these school buffers overlap. So while a store may be 1500 m from school A, it is only 750 m from school B. Therefore, it counts as being within 1000 m from a school, and should only be counted as being in the 1000m for school B, and not counted for school A. Where a store is within 2000 m of two schools (but not within 1000 m) it needs to count toward the school it is closest to.

So ideally I want the dataset to look like:

| School | Stores1000m | Stores2000m |
| --- | --- | --- |
| School A | 3 | 6 |
| School B | 2 | 7 |

So I used the st_union function in sf to combine the buffers. This worked well for producing a beautiful map, but then when I used lengths and st_intersects to count the stores within the buffers, it only returned a single number for each type of zone (1000 m vs 2000 m)

Sample data: [Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iuHbNjDtQjuV7K7BfdUmA27NP5VFNpRxxxQwbnMCCPM/edit?usp=sharing)

```
county.sf <- get_acs(state = "MO",
                     county = c( "St. Louis City"),
                     geography = "tract",
                     variables = "B03002_001", 
                     output="wide", 
                     geometry = TRUE) %>%
  sf::st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003")
  
class(county.sf)

# School data
school <- read.csv("C:\\myfile1.csv")
school.sf <- st_as_sf(school, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = "epsg:4326") 
school.sf.utm <- st_transform(school.sf, crs = "ESRI:102003")


# Store data
store <- import("C:\\myfile2.csv")
store.sf <- st_as_sf(store, coords = c("XCoord", "YCoord"), crs = "ESRI:102696") 
store.sf.utm <- st_transform(store.sf, crs = "ESRI:102003")


elem.buff <-st_buffer(school.sf.utm, 1000)     
elem.buff2 <-st_buffer(school.sf.utm, 2000) 

pts_com<-st_union(elem.buff)
pts_pol<-st_cast(pts_com, "POLYGON")

pts_com2<-st_union(elem.buff2)
pts_pol2<-st_cast(pts_com2, "POLYGON")


#unmerged zone map
ex.map<- tm_shape(county.sf) +
  tm_polygons() + 
  
  tm_shape(elem.buff) +
  tm_borders(col="red") +  
  
  tm_shape(school.sf.utm) +
  tm_dots(col = "red") +
  
  tm_shape(elem.buff2) +
  tm_borders(col="blue") + 
    
  tm_shape(pts_pol) +
  tm_borders(col="black") +
  
  tm_shape(store.sf.utm) +
  tm_dots() 
ex.map




#merged zones map

ex.map<- tm_shape(county.sf) +
  tm_polygons() + 
  
  #(elem.buff) +
  #tm_borders(col="red") +  
  
  tm_shape(school.sf.utm) +
  tm_dots(col = "red") +
  
  #tm_shape(elem.buff2) +
  #tm_borders(col="blue") + 
  
  tm_shape(pts_pol) +
  tm_borders(col="red") +
  
  tm_shape(store.sf.utm) +
  tm_dots() +

  tm_shape(pts_pol2) +
  tm_borders(col="blue")
ex.map



(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(elem.buff, store.sf.utm))) #gives per school but ignores overlapping
(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(pts_com, store.sf.utm)))

(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(elem.buff2, store.sf.utm)))
(school$pt_count <- lengths(st_intersects(pts_com2, store.sf.utm)))
```

Comment: Hi revere2323. _I include all of my code and a link to sample data below._ While this seems like a good idea for you, this makes it really hard to answer the question. A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a sample input included in your question will increase your chances to get a great answer for your question.

Comment: I am not sure how I could do that here. This is fairly specific as there needs to be overlapping buffers and the stores need to also fall within those buffers for the example to make sense. I only included a single zip-code of schools so it is as minimal as I can make it. It is true that I only need to hypothetically know how to do this--but thank you for the suggestion, I will sleep on it if I ca find a way to make this simpler.

Comment: If you are dead set on avoiding double counting - i.e. each store needs to have exactly one nearest school - buffer may not be your best approach. Consider st_nearest_feature 
 (to get the nearest school) followed by st_distance (to measure its distance) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Updated, more efficient answer for larger data:

I admit, the previous answer which relied on making a `list` column of all schools, and used `unnest()` to find every combination is not suitable for larger data.

As suggested by @JindraLacko in the comments, `st_nearest_feature()` is your friend here; unsurprisingly it is more efficient than the 'manual' method I proposed.

As above, load libraries and data

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

library(tmap)
tmap_mode('view')


read_xlsx('Schools and Stores_all.xlsx', sheet = 1) %>% 
  st_as_sf(., coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = "epsg:4326") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003") %>% 
  {. ->> school.sf.utm}

read_xlsx('Schools and Stores_all.xlsx', sheet = 2) %>% 
  st_as_sf(., coords = c("XCoord", "YCoord"), crs = "ESRI:102696") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003") %>% 
  {. ->> store.sf.utm}
```

Then, we use `st_join()` to join the stores and schools data, and specify `join = st_nearest_feature` so it joins (the name of) each store's nearest school. Then we join each school's geometry in using `left_join()`. See `?st_join` for more details. So ultimately, this gives us each store's nearest school.

```
# find the closest school to each store (this is the school it counts towards)
store.sf.utm %>% 
  rename(
    store_geometry = geometry
  ) %>% 
  st_join(
    school.sf.utm, 
    join = st_nearest_feature
  ) %>% 
  left_join(
    school.sf.utm %>% 
      as_tibble %>% 
      rename(
        school_geometry = geometry
      )
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> all_combos}

all_combos

# Simple feature collection with 2603 features and 1 field
# Active geometry column: store_geometry
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 489948.3 ymin: 131719.1 xmax: 501438.8 ymax: 157382.1
# Projected CRS: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
# # A tibble: 2,603 x 3
#        store_geometry School                               school_geometry
#           <POINT [m]> <chr>                                    <POINT [m]>
# 1  (489948.3 137420.8) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)
# 2  (490119.7 136712.7) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)
# 3  (490171.8 138758.2) Gateway Science Acad/st Louis    (491307.4 138787.2)
# 4  (490370.2 139681.3) Wilkinson Early Childhood Center (490930.4 140461.2)
# 5  (490568.3 137056.8) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)
# 6    (490475 139013.4) Gateway Science Acad/st Louis    (491307.4 138787.2)
# 7  (490527.6 139633.1) Wilkinson Early Childhood Center (490930.4 140461.2)
# 8  (490715.3 136690.1) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)
# 9  (490552.5 139805.9) Wilkinson Early Childhood Center (490930.4 140461.2)
# 10   (490790 138069.5) Gateway Science Acad/st Louis    (491307.4 138787.2)
# # ... with 2,593 more rows
```

Interestingly, we have dropped from 156 schools to 134. I assume this means there are 22 schools which are not the closest to any store.

```
# how many schools in all_combos?
all_combos %>% 
  summarise(
    n_schools = n_distinct(School)
  ) %>% 
  pull(n_schools)

# [1] 134
```

Now that we know which school is closest, calculate the distances between each store and it's nearest school.

```
# calculate distance from each store to each school
all_combos %>% 
  mutate(
    distance = as.numeric(st_distance(store_geometry, school_geometry, by_element = TRUE))
  ) %>% 
  filter(
    distance <= 2000
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> all_combos_2}

all_combos_2

# Simple feature collection with 2595 features and 2 fields
# Active geometry column: store_geometry
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 489948.3 ymin: 131719.1 xmax: 501438.8 ymax: 152889.7
# Projected CRS: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
# # A tibble: 2,595 x 4
#        store_geometry School                               school_geometry distance
# *          <POINT [m]> <chr>                                    <POINT [m]>    <dbl>
# 1  (489948.3 137420.8) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)    1419.
# 2  (490119.7 136712.7) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)    1003.
# 3  (490171.8 138758.2) Gateway Science Acad/st Louis    (491307.4 138787.2)    1136.
# 4  (490370.2 139681.3) Wilkinson Early Childhood Center (490930.4 140461.2)     960.
# 5  (490568.3 137056.8) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)     704.
# 6    (490475 139013.4) Gateway Science Acad/st Louis    (491307.4 138787.2)     863.
# 7  (490527.6 139633.1) Wilkinson Early Childhood Center (490930.4 140461.2)     921.
# 8  (490715.3 136690.1) Community Access Job Training    (491117.8 136616.5)     409.
# 9  (490552.5 139805.9) Wilkinson Early Childhood Center (490930.4 140461.2)     756.
# 10   (490790 138069.5) Gateway Science Acad/st Louis    (491307.4 138787.2)     885.
# # ... with 2,585 more rows
```

Work out how many stores are within 1000 m of their nearest school.

```
all_combos_2 %>%
  filter(
    distance <= 1000
  ) %>% 
  group_by(School) %>% 
  summarise(
    Stores1000m = n()
  ) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry %>% 
  {. ->> combo_sum_1000}

combo_sum_1000

# # A tibble: 134 x 2
#   School                                    Stores1000m
# * <chr>                                           <int>
# 1 Academy At Boys & Girls Town                       24
# 2 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Elementary School          18
# 3 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School               2
# 4 Adams Elementary School                            12
# 5 Ames Visual/perf. Arts                             25
# 6 Ashland Elementary And Br.                         49
# 7 Aspire Academy                                     26
# 8 Beaumont Cte High School                           46
# 9 Bishop DuBourg High School                          4
# 10 Bryan Hill Elementary School                       19
# # ... with 124 more rows
```

And the same for 2000 m.

```
all_combos_2 %>%
  filter(
    distance <= 2000
  ) %>% 
  group_by(School) %>% 
  summarise(
    Stores2000m = n()
  ) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry %>% 
  {. ->> combo_sum_2000}

combo_sum_2000

# # A tibble: 134 x 2
#   School                                    Stores2000m
# * <chr>                                           <int>
# 1 Academy At Boys & Girls Town                       24
# 2 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Elementary School          18
# 3 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School               2
# 4 Adams Elementary School                            12
# 5 Ames Visual/perf. Arts                             25
# 6 Ashland Elementary And Br.                         49
# 7 Aspire Academy                                     28
# 8 Beaumont Cte High School                           52
# 9 Bishop DuBourg High School                          4
# 10 Bryan Hill Elementary School                       19
# # ... with 124 more rows
```

And then join the two tables together.

```
combo_sum_1000 %>% 
  full_join(combo_sum_2000) %>% 
  {. ->> combo_sum_joined}

combo_sum_joined

# # A tibble: 134 x 3
#    School                                    Stores1000m Stores2000m
#    <chr>                                           <int>       <int>
# 1  Academy At Boys & Girls Town                       24          24
# 2  AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Elementary School          18          18
# 3  AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School               2           2
# 4  Adams Elementary School                            12          12
# 5  Ames Visual/perf. Arts                             25          25
# 6  Ashland Elementary And Br.                         49          49
# 7  Aspire Academy                                     26          28
# 8  Beaumont Cte High School                           46          52
# 9  Bishop DuBourg High School                          4           4
# 10 Bryan Hill Elementary School                       19          19
# # ... with 124 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer, if I have interpreted the problem correctly.

From what I got from the question, you want to know how many stores are within 1000 and 2000 m of each school, *but stores are only counted towards the school they are closest to* - is this right?

Minimal code setup, by saving your sample data as an `.xlsx` file in the working directory:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

read_xlsx('Schools and Stores.xlsx', sheet = 1) %>% 
  st_as_sf(., coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = "epsg:4326") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003") %>% 
  {. ->> school.sf.utm}

read_xlsx('Schools and Stores.xlsx', sheet = 2) %>% 
  st_as_sf(., coords = c("XCoord", "YCoord"), crs = "ESRI:102696") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "ESRI:102003") %>% 
  {. ->> store.sf.utm}
```

Firstly, to reduce the number of stores in the dataset we keep only stores within a 2 km buffer of all schools (This might have been what you did by using `st_union()` after `st_buffer()`). This reduces the number of stores from 2603 to 191.

```
# step 1 - keep only stores within a 2km buffer of all schools, to reduce number of stores to work with
stores.sf.utm %>% 
  filter(
    st_intersects(stores.sf.utm, school.sf.utm %>% st_buffer(2000), sparse = FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  rename(
    geometry_stores = geometry
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> stores_2000}

stores_2000

# Simple feature collection with 191 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 496820.2 ymin: 138115.8 xmax: 500484.2 ymax: 141987.8
# Projected CRS: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
# # A tibble: 191 x 1
#       geometry_stores
#           <POINT [m]>
# 1   (496820.2 139441)
# 2 (496848.1 140725.7)
# 3 (496987.8 138959.5)
# 4 (497052.2 139815.4)
# 5   (497030 140286.7)
# 6 (497122.5 138900.1)
# 7 (497033.2 140646.1)
# 8 (497099.8 140279.6)
# 9 (497199.7 138687.5)
# 10 (497154.4 139805.9)
# # ... with 181 more rows
```

Next, we generate all potential combinations of schools and remaining stores. I assign a `store_id` so we can tell which store is which (without using it's `geometry`).

```
# generate all schools~stores combos
stores_2000 %>% 
  mutate(
    store_id = row_number(),
    schools = list(school.sf.utm)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c('schools')) %>% 
  rename(
    geometry_school = geometry
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> all_combos}

all_combos

# Simple feature collection with 3438 features and 2 fields
# Active geometry column: geometry_stores
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 496820.2 ymin: 138115.8 xmax: 500484.2 ymax: 141987.8
# Projected CRS: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
# # A tibble: 3,438 x 4
#      geometry_stores store_id School                                    geometry_school
#          <POINT [m]>    <int> <chr>                                         <POINT [m]>
#  1 (496820.2 139441)        1 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School (498610.1 140067.7)
#  2 (496820.2 139441)        1 Collegiate School Of Med/bio          (496797.7 140597.6)
#  3 (496820.2 139441)        1 Dewey Sch.-internat'l. Studies        (499626.5 139130.3)
#  4 (496820.2 139441)        1 Eagle Fox Park                        (498015.9 139324.1)
#  5 (496820.2 139441)        1 Education Therap Support At Madison   (476270.1 131682.7)
#  6 (496820.2 139441)        1 Hodgen Elementary School              (497853.4 140290.1)
#  7 (496820.2 139441)        1 Humboldt Academy Of Higher Lrning     (499410.4 138707.3)
#  8 (496820.2 139441)        1 Lafayette Preparatory Academy           (498812.6 140006)
#  9 (496820.2 139441)        1 Lift For Life Academy                 (500025.8 139526.4)
# 10 (496820.2 139441)        1 Lift For Life Academy High School     (500025.8 139526.4)
# # ... with 3,428 more rows
```

This means we can work out the distance from each store to each school. We then keep only combinations within 2000 m of each other (these are formed from stores and schools at opposite sides of the original 2 km buffer, which is why their distance exceeds 2 km).

```
# calculate distance from each store to each school
all_combos %>% 
  mutate(
    distance = as.numeric(st_distance(geometry_stores, geometry_school, by_element = TRUE))
  ) %>% 
  filter(
    distance <= 2000
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> all_combos_2}

all_combos_2

# Simple feature collection with 2231 features and 3 fields
# Active geometry column: geometry_stores
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 496820.2 ymin: 138115.8 xmax: 500484.2 ymax: 141987.8
# Projected CRS: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
# # A tibble: 2,231 x 5
#        geometry_stores store_id School                                    geometry_school distance
# *          <POINT [m]>    <int> <chr>                                         <POINT [m]>    <dbl>
# 1    (496820.2 139441)        1 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School (498610.1 140067.7)   1896. 
# 2    (496820.2 139441)        1 Collegiate School Of Med/bio          (496797.7 140597.6)   1157. 
# 3    (496820.2 139441)        1 Eagle Fox Park                        (498015.9 139324.1)   1201. 
# 4    (496820.2 139441)        1 Hodgen Elementary School              (497853.4 140290.1)   1337. 
# 5    (496820.2 139441)        1 Mckinley Class. Leadership Ac.        (498355.8 139560.4)   1540. 
# 6    (496820.2 139441)        1 Nahed Chapman New American Academy    (496615.8 140605.6)   1182. 
# 7    (496820.2 139441)        1 Shenandoah Elementary School            (496821 139360.4)     80.6
# 8    (496820.2 139441)        1 Sigel Elementary Comm. Ed. Center     (498603.2 139613.7)   1791. 
# 9    (496820.2 139441)        1 St. Louis Christian Academy           (497245.5 140196.9)    867. 
# 10 (496848.1 140725.7)        2 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School (498610.1 140067.7)   1881. 
# # ... with 2,221 more rows
```

Now if my understanding is correct, each store counts only towards the school it is closest to. So, we keep only the school each store is closest to using `filter()`:

```
# first, keep only the closest school to each store
all_combos_2 %>% 
  arrange(store_id, distance) %>% 
  group_by(store_id) %>% 
  filter(
    distance == min(distance)
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> all_combos_3}
# so now we have the closest school to each store

all_combos_3

# Simple feature collection with 223 features and 3 fields
# Active geometry column: geometry_stores
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 496820.2 ymin: 138115.8 xmax: 500484.2 ymax: 141987.8
# Projected CRS: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
# # A tibble: 223 x 5
# # Groups:   store_id [191]
#        geometry_stores store_id School                           geometry_school distance
# *          <POINT [m]>    <int> <chr>                                <POINT [m]>    <dbl>
# 1    (496820.2 139441)        1 Shenandoah Elementary School   (496821 139360.4)     80.6
# 2  (496848.1 140725.7)        2 Collegiate School Of Med/bio (496797.7 140597.6)    138. 
# 3  (496987.8 138959.5)        3 Shenandoah Elementary School   (496821 139360.4)    434. 
# 4  (497052.2 139815.4)        4 St. Louis Christian Academy  (497245.5 140196.9)    428. 
# 5    (497030 140286.7)        5 St. Louis Christian Academy  (497245.5 140196.9)    233. 
# 6  (497122.5 138900.1)        6 Shenandoah Elementary School   (496821 139360.4)    550. 
# 7  (497033.2 140646.1)        7 Collegiate School Of Med/bio (496797.7 140597.6)    240. 
# 8  (497099.8 140279.6)        8 St. Louis Christian Academy  (497245.5 140196.9)    168. 
# 9  (497199.7 138687.5)        9 Shenandoah Elementary School   (496821 139360.4)    772. 
# 10 (497154.4 139805.9)       10 St. Louis Christian Academy  (497245.5 140196.9)    402. 
# # ... with 213 more rows
```

Notice that we have 223 rows now. This means there are 32 duplicates (223 - 191);  where there are two (or more) closest schools, and they are the same distance away from the store (in this example max duplicates = 2). However you choose to handle these is up to you. In this example I will leave them in the data, but if you only want a single school, you may choose the first alphabetically or a random choice etc.

So now, we can calculate how many of the stores are within 1000 m of the (their closest) school:

```
# now, how many closest stores are within 1000 m of each school
all_combos_3 %>% 
  filter(
    distance <= 1000
  ) %>% 
  group_by(School) %>% 
  summarise(
    Stores1000m = n()
  ) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry %>% 
  {. ->> combo_sum_1000}

combo_sum_1000

# # A tibble: 16 x 2
#    School                                Stores1000m
#  * <chr>                                       <int>
#  1 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School           2
#  2 Collegiate School Of Med/bio                    4
#  3 Dewey Sch.-internat'l. Studies                  6
#  4 Eagle Fox Park                                 37
#  5 Hodgen Elementary School                       17
#  6 Humboldt Academy Of Higher Lrning              10
#  7 Lafayette Preparatory Academy                   1
#  8 Lift For Life Academy                           8
#  9 Lift For Life Academy High School               8
# 10 Mckinley Class. Leadership Ac.                  7
# 11 Peabody Elementary School                      48
# 12 Shenandoah Elementary School                    6
# 13 Sigel Elementary Comm. Ed. Center               7
# 14 St. Louis Christian Academy                     7
# 15 St. Louis College Prep High School             14
# 16 St. Louis College Prep Middle School           14
```

And the same approach for stores within 2000 m:

```
# 2000 m
all_combos_3 %>% 
  filter(
    distance <= 2000
  ) %>% 
  group_by(School) %>% 
  summarise(
    Stores2000m = n()
  ) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry %>% 
  {. ->> combo_sum_2000}

combo_sum_2000

# # A tibble: 16 x 2
#    School                                Stores2000m
#  * <chr>                                       <int>
#  1 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School           2
#  2 Collegiate School Of Med/bio                    4
#  3 Dewey Sch.-internat'l. Studies                  6
#  4 Eagle Fox Park                                 37
#  5 Hodgen Elementary School                       18
#  6 Humboldt Academy Of Higher Lrning              10
#  7 Lafayette Preparatory Academy                   1
#  8 Lift For Life Academy                           8
#  9 Lift For Life Academy High School               8
# 10 Mckinley Class. Leadership Ac.                  7
# 11 Peabody Elementary School                      53
# 12 Shenandoah Elementary School                    7
# 13 Sigel Elementary Comm. Ed. Center               7
# 14 St. Louis Christian Academy                     7
# 15 St. Louis College Prep High School             24
# 16 St. Louis College Prep Middle School           24
```

And of course we can join these two datasets to match your desired output.

```
combo_sum_1000 %>% 
  full_join(combo_sum_2000) %>% 
  {. ->> combo_sum_joined}

combo_sum_joined

# # A tibble: 16 x 3
#    School                                Stores1000m Stores2000m
#    <chr>                                       <int>       <int>
#  1 AcademyOf Envt Sci/math Middle School           2           2
#  2 Collegiate School Of Med/bio                    4           4
#  3 Dewey Sch.-internat'l. Studies                  6           6
#  4 Eagle Fox Park                                 37          37
#  5 Hodgen Elementary School                       17          18
#  6 Humboldt Academy Of Higher Lrning              10          10
#  7 Lafayette Preparatory Academy                   1           1
#  8 Lift For Life Academy                           8           8
#  9 Lift For Life Academy High School               8           8
# 10 Mckinley Class. Leadership Ac.                  7           7
# 11 Peabody Elementary School                      48          53
# 12 Shenandoah Elementary School                    6           7
# 13 Sigel Elementary Comm. Ed. Center               7           7
# 14 St. Louis Christian Academy                     7           7
# 15 St. Louis College Prep High School             14          24
# 16 St. Louis College Prep Middle School           14          24
```

I hope my interpretation of the problem is correct, I admit it is a little confusing as we switch between grouping by stores then schools etc. But I think this works.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will test this tomorrow and get back to you, but this is amazing, and I think what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay @hugh-allan, you are a life saver, but for whatever reason when I use this on the whole data set I am only getting 20 total schools. Note a few things: (1) I gave a sample of schools all in the same zipcode, but I have schools across all St. Louis City. I have 157 total schools. So I am not sure if that's what is affecting this, but I don't understand why it would. The final result of only 20 schools is definitely not right 

I have been trying to trouble shoot all day, and I can't figure our what the issue is. Let me know if it helps I can add all of the schools to the sample data.

Comment: If you provide the full data I can have a look when I get a chance. First question - are you 100% sure that more than 20 schools are within 2 km of a store? This might sound obvious, but for example mapping them might be a good way to check the projections are all correct etc. Assuming they are, see if you can find at what stage the schools are lost (`stores_2000`, `all_combos`, `all_combos_2` etc). Add the full data to the question if you like.

Comment: I added the full data to the link above. There are 156 schools. all_combos shows 3120 obs, all_combos_2 shows 46, and all_combos_3 shows 20...so not sure.

And I am 100% sure that more schools are within 2000m, as I have already mapped the city and stores.

Comment: Okay, right now I am attempting to complete this by skipping the first step. Given I had already made sure all the stores and schools were in St. Louis City, I don't think it is super necessary. Unfortunately, this has made the processing time go through the roof, but I will let you know if it works.

Comment: You have been so helpful thus far: I have also asked a completely different question that may be easier that would solve the problem in a different way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832048/r-sf-i-have-points-and-2-buffers-around-each-point-how-to-combine-the-points, just wanted to let you know!

Comment: I have added a new answer which uses `st_join()` and `st_nearest_feature()`, which has worked for the dataset of ~150 schools.

Comment: Hi @hugh-allan. This worked! It gave me exactly what I need. This is a weird request, but I am definitely going to include you as an acknowledgement in my dissertation presentation and any corresponding papers that come out of this work. I have changed variable names for the sake of the internet, so the end result will be a bit different in interpretation than here, but you have been so incredibly helpful I don't know how else to express gratitude. Please let me know if you do NOT want to be acknowledged. I will let you know the conclusions beforehand :)

Comment: That is fine, I'm glad this has been helpful :)